# Xcode 13 vs iOS 14.4 simulator

Tags: simulator, ios14, xcode13

I updated my Xcode to Xcode 13, I can able to run the app on iOS 15 simulators and everything working fine

But when I run the app on iOS 14.4 simulator , text in the textfields are cute off when typing and I unable to delete the entered text from textfield
I do see some animation issue on iOS 14.4 simulator
but everything is working fine on iOS 15 simulator , device and iOS 14 device

Only issue with iOS **14.4 simulator**  with Xcode 13 can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved, problem is with Mac OS version
I was on Big Sur  11.5.2

After updating my Mac OS to Big Sur 11.6
App is working fine on simulator with iOS 14